# Bigcommerce stencil product grid or card

Tags: bigcommerce

i need to get the grid of few products or `card.html` for a single product. I tried to use below two codes, but grid is coming blank and card doesn't getting product details inside it. Can you please help me here?

```js
window.stencilUtils.api.product.getById(177, { template: 'products/card' }, (err, response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```js
window.stencilUtils.api.product.getById(177, { template: 'products/grid' }, (err, response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be approached with the [{{#each}} Handlebars Helper](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#loop-control-flow) as seen in the grid.html template: https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/templates/components/products/grid.html

Consider the context of the grid.html template, it is called through [product-listing.html](https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/templates/components/category/product-listing.html) which could have a different context than where this script is being called. The Product Card Model can be found on the Dev Center here as well: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/common-objects#common-product-card-model